# InDesign Source file access

Tags: adobe-indesign

My manager wants to give our account managers access to my InDesign source files to make last-minute text changes to client brochures. I have been asked to create a 2nd source file and save the file within the manager's folder on our server for them to access. She thinks keeping a master 1st version of the InDesign source file within my folder is a good idea, just in case the managers mess up the formatting within the 2nd version of the source files. I disagree, thinking they will not make any formatting mistakes so drastic that we will have to revert back to my "Master source file" and that we should only have 1 InDesign source file and not 2. This entire process is upper management's idea. What do you all think? Is 2 source files a good idea or a bad idea?

Comment: How good is your backup strategy otherwise? You only need someone to irrevocably screw up your only copy of a source once.

Comment: ALWAYS keep a master source file. You have no idea how badly accounts managers will mess up your files. Even better: if possible, use InCopy so the scope of what the account managers can screw up is limited (but still keep an extra master source file as backup).

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I have never used InCopy. How would I utilize it within this process? I guess I will research, but any additional advice would be helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, in reality what is being suggested is a poor mans version control system. It would be better if you used some sort a version control system for this instead, since it would allow you to track changes made and eliminate guesswork when copying since it will just correctly copy everything needed in new file structure. But yes keeping a backup is the thing to do again version control maks it easy for you to make this backup.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be **amazed** at what can happen in the hands of untrained InDesign users.

##### Your manager is correct.

Keep a **solid** original version of the file — either yourself or via a stable, reliable backup system.

---

<sub>Although the manager is correct here, it shouldn't *really* matter if the manager is correct or not. That's what the boss wants you to do.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your manager is correct. Share the files, but keep your own copy intact, to protect the original work from accidental damage.